# Eclipse, Change maven settings-security.xml based on project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is it possible to change settings-security.xml file based on project in Eclipse?
We can set, on maven settings, the path for settings.xml or use the default root folder (.m2) based on environment variable (maven.home) but not the security path, which is still retrieved from the main root.
I need to change settings based on project (so also the repository url) but i need to change also security file connected to it, instead of remove or replace the file, is there a way faster?
Thanks

Comment: My simple question is: Why? What is exactly the reason ?

Comment: If i need to switch between projects (for different companies) inside the same workspace and with different security settings.

Comment: Best would be to make a git repo from ".m2/" without "repository" and use branches for switching...